# Field names returned in search snippet. How to hide?

Tags: entities, search

Field names are being returned in the search snippets on my search results page, like so:

> Academic Culture
>
> Body Text: The academic culture of your host country may be quite
>   different from what you experience here at ...

The bit that reads "Body Text:" is the field name. What's weird is that the field name is only returned when the snippet is at the beginning of the field. So, depending on the search it could return something like this:

> Academic Culture
>
> ... academic culture of your host country may be quite
>   different from what you experience here at ...

Note the absence of "Body Text:".

Is there a way to disable/hide field names in the search snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually a view mode for Search results, you can control the field label visibility settings there. See Admin >> Structure >> Content Types >> [Content Type] >> Manage Display >> Custom Display Settings. Activate the view modes for search and customize away.

Comment: @fullerja Any idea how to customize the Search Snippet field? I can't find a way to edit this. And it still shows for example the publish date or other fields that i don't need. Thanks in advance!